# How to efficiently find all the files matching a particular suffix in all the directories?

Tags: go

I need to recursively find all the files in a directory which can have lot of sub-directories too. I was wondering if there is any way it can only give me `*.json` files only?
I have below method which does the job and gives me all files recursively in all the directories but I am not sure whether I am doing it right by using `HasSuffix` here. I am new to golang so I not sure if there is any better or efficient way to do this.

```
func WalkDir(root string) ([]string, error) {
    var files []string
    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !info.IsDir() && strings.HasSuffix(path, "json") {
            files = append(files, path)
        }
        return nil
    })
    return files, err
}
```

Also how can I modify above method so that it can give me all the files matching `*.json` or `*.txt` suffix. Basically it should be able to work with suffix array and give me all files matching that. What is the efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to ensure the dot (.) is present before the file suffix too.

Also as noted by @maxm, `WalkDir` is preferred according to [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Walk):

> Walk is less efficient than WalkDir, introduced in Go 1.16, which
> avoids calling os.Lstat on every visited file or directory.

To check for a match of multiple suffixes you can try:

```
func WalkDir(root string, exts []string) ([]string, error) {
    var files []string
    err := filepath.WalkDir(root, func(path string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
        if d.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        for _, s := range exts {
            if strings.HasSuffix(path, "."+s) {
                files = append(files, path)
                return nil
            }
        }

        return nil
    })
    return files, err
}
```

And to use:

```
files, err := WalkDir("/home", []string{"json", "txt"})
```

Comment: filepath.WalkDir would be faster/better here, you can avoid calling `stat()` on each file

Comment: Thanks for an update. Seeing compilation issue with `info.IsDir()` line. Maybe it needs to be replaced with something else. @colm.anseo

Comment: with `WalkDir` the callback function signature changes. I've fixed the code to accept the `fs.DirEntry` parameter.

Comment: Thanks make sense now. Also this just came into my mind, is there any way to remove duplicate files from `files string array`? Will current implementation will take care of it automatically or I need to write another helper method to dedup the files? @colm.anseo

Comment: The "walk" will have unique file paths. Since symlinks are not followed - there's no chance of cyclical/repeated traversals.